# Why is String being interpreted as a type?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell, plutus-pab

According [type applications](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application), this extension `allows to give explicit type arguments to a polymorphic function`.

```
type VestingSchema =
             Endpoint "give" GiveParams
         .\/ Endpoint "grab" ()
-- ...
endpoints :: Contract () VestingSchema Text ()
endpoints = awaitPromise (give' `select` grab') >> endpoints
   where
     give' = endpoint @"give" give
     grab' = endpoint @"grab" $ const grab
```

This does not allows to give values to a polymorphic function, so I have figured out that actually those "strings" at `@"give"` and `@"grab"` are actually something similar to types, because the type `Endpoint` has this type/kind signature:

```
type Endpoint :: ghc-prim-0.6.1:GHC.Types.Symbol
                 -> * -> row-types-1.0.1.2:Data.Row.Internal.Row *
type Endpoint l a =
  l
  row-types-1.0.1.2:Data.Row.Internal..== (Wallet.Types.EndpointValue
                                             a,
                                           Plutus.Contract.Effects.ActiveEndpoint)
  :: row-types-1.0.1.2:Data.Row.Internal.Row *
        -- Defined in ‘Plutus.Contract.Request
```

So that `l` has kind `Symbol`. Why this is working with TypeApplications? Can I use this "give" and "grab" as type and/or type constructors anywhere in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension that you are after is not `TypeAplications`, but `DataKinds`. I liked the explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558648/what-is-the-datakinds-extension-of-haskell

Comment: `DataKinds` explains why `Endpoint` can receive a type as argument and return a concret type, but it does not explain why I am allowed to use `"give"` and `"grab"` as type references on `@` operator argument

Comment: No, because of `DataKinds` you can use `"give"` as a type, both in `Endpoint` and in the type application. Because of the `DataKinds`extension, `String` becomes a kind and the values of type `String` become types of kind `String`.

Comment: Also see the example Lars gave in the lecture https://youtu.be/qoUfgaHs1CI?list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x230-g-U02issX5BiWAgmSi&t=855:
1. type application allows us to disambiguate the type of callEndpoint
2. data kinds allows us to use type-level strings